# Install apk manually on device : error 103

Tags: android, intellij-idea, apk

I try to install an apk (build by IntelliJ) **manually** on my phone (GT-B5330 running Android 4.0.4).

- Intellij generate MyApp.apk (using Build > Artifact > Rebuild...)
- Phone setting : Security > Device Administration > Unknown sources is checked
- I uninstall existing "debug" version of MyApp on the phone
- I connect my phone to the pc with USB cable and transfert MyApp.apk to the phone sdcard.
- On the phone I browse the sdcard and click MyApp.apk
- I see the permissions required by MyApp and try to install it.
- I receive a message "Application not installed"

Looking at logcat I found those logs:

```
01-25 10:55:15.668: INFO/ApplicationPolicy(1448): isApplicationInstallationEnabled
01-25 10:55:15.668: WARN/PackageManager(1448): verifying app can be installed or not
01-25 10:55:15.748: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(1216): id=3872 Removed idx=3 Map Size=4
01-25 10:55:15.748: INFO/SurfaceFlinger(1216): id=3872 Removed idx=-2 Map Size=4
01-25 10:55:16.148: DEBUG/dalvikvm(1448): GC_EXPLICIT freed 744K, 34% free 13115K/19655K, paused 5ms+11ms
01-25 10:55:16.148: DEBUG/InstallAppProgress(22326): Installation error code: -103
```

I tried to find the meaning of this **error code -103** but I didn't find anything.

I'm wondering what can be wrong and how can I fix/investigate the issue?

Note that :

- when I run the from my IDE : it is installed and work properly.
- some native libs are packaged with MyApp.apk

Am I missing something obvious ? Other security setting to change ?

Any help will be greatly appreciate.

Comment: Try uninstalling your debug version first, then install from APK. You cant have both on at once. Though it usually tells you this, so it could be something else. (aka, you have probably already tried this)

Comment: While running from the IDE, the apk is signed with the debug key. In your other build way, are you using the same key for signing? Do you even sign it?

Comment: @Doomsknight : yes I've uninstalled the "debug" app before (I edited my post to signal this fact)

Comment: @WarrenFaith I look further in my IDE settings... and indeed the apk was generated "unsigned" by default by my IDE. (signing it with debug key solve the issue). Thanks please put it as an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While running from the IDE, the apk is signed with the debug key.

I assume that you first mentioned build method might use another key or no one at all. None at all is my guess as otherwise you should have got a message that the signature differs.

Here is a screenshot to show how to sign an apk with IDEA12

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You have already installed this app in your device?
Because probably you are trying to install an application already exists, signed with a different key.